# How to resize image coming from media in frontend?

Tags: magento-1.4, magento-1.5, magento

i am trying to resize the images on frontend that are uploaded to my folder in media. I tried this code but its not displaying anything for me :(

```
   foreach($this->myBanners() as $_testing_banners){

    $img_location = Mage::getBaseUrl('media'). 'Banners/images/demand/'.$_testing_banners['bannerimage'];

    $image= new Varien_Image($img_location);

    echo '<img src="'.$image->resize(200, 200).'" alt="" />';

    }
```

although this shows images but original size :( not resized :(

```
foreach($this->myBanners() as $_testing_banners){

$img_location = Mage::getBaseUrl('media'). 'Banners/images/demand/'.$_testing_banners['bannerimage'];


echo '<img src="'.$img_location.'" alt="" />';

}
```

so how can i resize them ?????
any idea ???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this way it will work.

```
 foreach($this->myBanners() as $_testing_banners){

    $img_location = Mage::getBaseDir('media'). 'Banners/images/demand/'.$_testing_banners['bannerimage'];

    $imageResized = Mage::getBaseDir('media'). 'Banners/images/demand/resized/'.$_testing_banners['bannerimage'];          

    $image= new Varien_Image($img_location);
    $image->resize(200, 200);
    $image->save($imageResized);

    echo '<img src="'.Mage::getBaseUrl('media'). 'Banners/images/demand/resized/'.$_testing_banners['bannerimage'].'" alt="" />';

    }
```

- Used getBaseDir instead of getBaseUrl.
- Saved image after resize
- Used the resized image path in image source

Hope it helps.

Comment: M still getting a blank page :( why is that so

Comment: This worked for me with one change, in my case the `getBaseDir` didn't return a trailing slash so I added one.

Comment: This should never be used within template.
It will lead to resizing all output images each request and each time template is rendered. All logic should be within controller or model. You can also write a helper that uses some caching for resizing media image.